# Merging two sorted linked lists into a third linked list (sorting and merging error)

Tags: java, sorting, singly-linked-list

The following code is meant to do the the listed tasks

1: create 3 linked lists
2: populate the first two
3: sort the first two
4: merge the first two linked lists with the third one by removing nodes from each of the first two, saving the data, and inserting it into the third list

the code to do that is as follows

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Node { //stores int values

public int data;
public Node next;

public Node(int d){
    data = d;
    next = null;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public void displayNode() { 
System.out.print(data);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
class NodeList {

private Node first;

public NodeList(){
    first = null;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first == null;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public void inputList(int n){

int x = 0;
Node newNode = null;
Node last = null;
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

    //System.out.printf("Enter data for node %d: ", i + 1);
    x = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    newNode = new Node(x);

    if (isEmpty()){ 
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode; 
        }
    else { 
        last.next = newNode;
        last = last.next; 
        }
    } 
System.out.println();
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public void selectionSort(){

Node p = null;
Node q = null;
Node r = null;
int t = 0;

if (isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("List is empty");
    }
else if(first.next != null){ 
    p = first;
    while (p.next != null){
        q = first;
        while (q.next != null){
            if (q.data > q.next.data){
                r = q.next;
            }
            q = q.next;
        }
        //System.out.printf("%d\n", r.data);
        t = p.data; 
        p.data = r.data;
        r.data = t;
        p = p.next;
    }
    //System.out.println("List is sorted");
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public int deleteFirst(){ 

    int x = 0;

    if (isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("List is empty");
    }
    else {
        x = first.data;
        first = first.next;
        //System.out.println("First node is deleted");
    }
    return x;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public void displayList(){

Node curr = null; 

if (isEmpty()){ 
    System.out.println("null");
}
else{
    curr = first;
    while (curr != null){

        curr.displayNode();
        System.out.printf("\n");
        curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
System.out.printf("\n");
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public void insert(int key){ 

    Node prev = null;
    Node curr = first;
    Node newNode = new Node(key);

    while ( (curr != null) &&(curr.data < key) ){

        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
        }

    if (curr == first){
        first = newNode;
        }

    else {
        prev.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = curr;
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
class MergeLists {

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

NodeList List_A = new NodeList();
NodeList List_B = new NodeList();
NodeList List_C = new NodeList();
String s;
String next;
char choice;
boolean continued = true;

List_A.inputList(5);
List_A.selectionSort();
List_A.displayList();

List_B.inputList(5);
List_B.selectionSort();
List_B.displayList();

while (continued){
System.out.printf("enter choice: \n");
System.out.printf("A: merge two ordered lists\n");
System.out.printf("B: view merged ordered list\n");
System.out.printf("C: exit\n");

s = in.nextLine();
choice = s.charAt(0);

switch(choice){

    case 'a':
        Mergelist(List_A, List_B, List_C);
        break;

    case 'b':
        List_C.displayList();
        break;

    case 'c':
        continued = false;
        break;

    default:
        System.out.print("Invalid entry\n");
    }//end switch
}//end while

}
public static void Mergelist(NodeList a, NodeList b, NodeList c){
    int x = 0;

    if (a.isEmpty() == false){
        while (a.isEmpty() == false){
            x = a.deleteFirst();
            c.insert(x);
        }
    }

    if (b.isEmpty() == false){
        while (b.isEmpty() == false){
            x = b.deleteFirst();
            c.insert(x);
        }
    }
}
}
```

problem is however with number 3 and 4. The code to sort the lists is erratic. Sometimes it sorts it completely, other times its barely sorted at all. In addition, with the 4th one, in some instances, only as much as 2 nodes are added to the 3rd list, other times, all would be added, in order

I am not sure why the 3rd one isnt sorting, but I believe that the problems in the 3rd one is causing problems in the 4th

If you can, any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Do you really ***HAVE*** to use `LinkedList`s? `Set`s seems to be a much more appropriate collection for what you're trying to do, in my opinion. I would gladly show you how to deal with your problem using `Set`s, would you be open to change your data structure :)

Comment: sorry, but it has to be with linked lists, designer specifications :(